# Azure DF CopyFromBlob Failing

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

I am trying to copy files from an Azure Blob to an Azure Data Lake using a data factory.  I keep running into this error and am not finding any information on what the parameter 'baseURI' maps to:

```
"errorCode": "2200",
"message": "ErrorCode=InvalidParameter,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=The value of the property &apos;baseUri&apos; is invalid: &apos;Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: baseUri&apos;.,Source=,''Type=System.ArgumentNullException,Message=Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: baseUri,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.MsiStoreServiceClient,'",
"failureType": "UserError",
"target": "CopyFromBlob"
```

I am using Powershell with json files.  Anything obvious that I am missing here?

Azure Data Lake Linked Service

```
{
    "name": "<redacted>",
    "properties": {
        "type": "AzureDataLakeStore",
        "typeProperties": {
            "dataLakeStoreUri": "<redacted>",
            "tenant": "<redacted>",
            "subscriptionId": "<redacted>",
            "resourceGroupName": "<redacted>"
        },
        "connectVia": {
            "referenceName": "<redacted>",
            "type": "IntegrationRuntimeReference"
        }
    }
}
```

Azure Blob Linked Service:

```
{
    "name": "<redacted>",
    "properties": {
        "type": "AzureStorage",
        "typeProperties": {
            "connectionString": {
                "type": "SecureString",
                "value": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<redacted>;AccountKey=<redacted>"
            }
        },
        "connectVia": {
           "referenceName": "<redacted>",
           "type": "IntegrationRuntimeReference"
        }   
    }
}
```

Data Lake Dataset

```
{
    "name": "<redacted>",
    "properties": {
        "type": "AzureDataLakeStoreFile",
        "linkedServiceName":{
            "referenceName": "<redacted>",
            "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
        },
        "typeProperties": {
            "folderPath": "<redacted>"
        }
    }
}
```

Blob DataSet

```
{
    "name": "<redacted>",
    "properties": {
        "type": "AzureBlob",
        "linkedServiceName": {
            "referenceName": "<redacted>",
            "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
        },
        "typeProperties": {
            "folderPath": "<redacted>",
        }
    }
}
```

Pipeline

```
{
"name": "<redacted>",
"properties": {
"activities":[

   {
        "name": "CopyFromBlob",
    "type": "Copy",
        "inputs": [
            {
                "referenceName": "<redacted>",
                "type": "DatasetReference"
            }
        ],
        "outputs": [
            {
                "referenceName": "<redacted>",
                "type": "DatasetReference"
            }
        ],

        "typeProperties": {
            "source": {
                "type": "BlobSource"
            },
            "sink": {
                "type": "AzureDataLakeStoreSink"
            }
        }
    }] 
}}
```

Powershell does the following:

```
1. Create Data Factory
2. Create Azure Integration Runtime
3. Create Azure Data Lake Linked Service
4. Create Azure Blob Linked Service
5. Create Azure Blob Dataset
6. Create Azure Data Lake Dataset
7. Create pipeline
8. Invoke pipeline
```

Comment: Please see [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and include the *smallest code possible* to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Odds are, there is a format issue with one of the JSON scripts that I included.  Each one is neccessary to build a Azure DF pipeline and invoke it.  What part of that should have been eliminated?

Answer (score 0):

Check your Azure Integration Runtime powershell command - are you defining a location and type? I ran into a very similar error (my null parameter was 'dictionary') when I forgot to define a location for my integration runtime.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is what I use:Set-AzureRmDataFactoryV2IntegrationRuntime -DataFactoryName "<redacted>" -name "<redacted>" -ResourceGroupName "szweather" -Type managed -location "East US"